# Does attack per second affect Demon Hunter's hatred generation?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I've noticed how 2-hand and 1-hand weapons can have the same DPS, but very different attack speed making attacks per second more or less frequent. Hatred generation skills' descriptions don't say if you get n hatred per hit or at 1x attack speed rate and I couldn't get any weapons with different enough APS rates to conclusively measure the hatred generation rate, but I suspect that affects it.

Does attack speed (attacks per second) affect how much hatred you can generate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The generation is per-use unless it says otherwise. This means the faster you shoot, the faster you generate.

I am fairly certain you do not need to hit anything to generate hatred. You can generate hatred by shooting at nothing.

Comment: Yeaa if you want to speed up regen, say after a long fight or something, you can just shift-click anywhere to regen some quick hatred.

Comment: This works also for the wizard. It does NOT work for the Barbarian: if there are no monsters around, Barbarians must at least kill a pot or a chair to generate fury.

Comment: And even pots don't cut it for the Monk :-)

Comment: @horatio: just to add the clarification on what I agree with you: the faster you shoot indeed generates faster hatred, but also causes you to spend hatred faster. In the end, based on statistics (not math), it is much more efficient to have a faster attack (higher attack speed) because you will have more critical hits in a unit of time and thus deal more dps.

this is a bit dubious, but it is easy to try in game: if you have cluster arrow with 2h xbow, you deal a massive amount of damage per hit, but you hit slower, therefore you deal fewer shots and each has the same amount for crit.